# Define X and y data for faceted geom_point plots with indexed data

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm trying to plot four scatter plots using ggplot2's faceting option, and I'm mentally stuck with my the dead end approach I headed into. I have numeric data for a samples A and B in conditions X and Y. I can plot all plots individually from a cartesian tibble but would love to have all in one.

```r
library(tidyverse)
test_cartesian = tibble(annotation = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4"),
                        data_A_X = c(1,2,3,4),
                        data_B_X = c(1.7,2.3,2.7,4.2),
                        data_A_Y = c(3,4,1,2),
                        data_B_Y = c(2.7,4.2,1.7,2.3))

test_indexed <- test_cartesian %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("data"),
    names_prefix = "data_",
    names_to = c("data_type", "sample_name"),
    values_to = "data",
    names_sep = "_"
  )
```

so the data looks like this:

```r
> test_indexed
# A tibble: 16 x 4
   annotation data_type sample_name  data
   <chr>      <chr>     <chr>       <dbl>
 1 G1         A         X             1  
 2 G1         B         X             1.7
 3 G1         A         Y             3  
 4 G1         B         Y             2.7
 5 G2         A         X             2  
 6 G2         B         X             2.3
 7 G2         A         Y             4  
 8 G2         B         Y             4.2
 9 G3         A         X             3  
10 G3         B         X             2.7
11 G3         A         Y             1  
12 G3         B         Y             1.7
13 G4         A         X             4  
14 G4         B         X             4.2
15 G4         A         Y             2  
16 G4         B         Y             2.3
```

Is there a way to use `x` and `y` coordinates directly from this? Something along this none working attempt?

```r
ggplot(test_indexed, aes(data_type)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(sample_name)
```

a plot like this is my objective :

|  | A_X | A_Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B_X | B_X/A_X | B_X/A_Y |
| B_Y | B_Y/A_X | B_Y/A_Y |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You took the right first step with your pivot, but it gets a bit easier when you split it into two steps:

```r
  library(tidyverse)
test_cartesian = tibble(annotation = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4"),
                        data_A_X = c(1,2,3,4),
                        data_B_X = c(1.7,2.3,2.7,4.2),
                        data_A_Y = c(3,4,1,2),
                        data_B_Y = c(2.7,4.2,1.7,2.3))

test_cartesian %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = matches('data_A_'),names_prefix = 'data_A_', names_to = 'A_cat', values_to = 'A') %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = matches('data_B_'),names_prefix = 'data_B_', names_to = 'B_cat', values_to = 'B') %>% 
  ggplot(aes(A,B)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(B_cat ~ A_cat)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks that is simpler, indeed! Just out of curiosity, there's no way this can be handled without keeping `x` and `y` coordinates in separate columns? (btw, I upvoted this, but due to my low rep, SO doesn't count it)

Comment: No, since you do need four variables in total, one each for the facet rows and columns and one each for the x- and y-coordinates. It's the ggplot-way I am afraid...